# How do I add a custom welcome tab to a Facebook fan page?

Tags: facebook

this is my first question on here so I do apologise in advance if I do something wrong. I'm a web designer, not a programmer (just for the record)!

I have to add a custom welcome tab to a Facebook fan page, and...I don't know how to do it. I have googled and found several tutorials, but I can't seem to follow any of them because my experience always deviates from what the guides lead me to expect!

The tutorial I've seen most recommended is this: http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/adding-iframe-application-to-facebook-fan-page/
However, I've tried it and I just don't get the same pages or forms as shown.

After I create and name a new app, the tutorial says I need to go to the Facebook Integration tab and fill in the fields "Tab URL", "Secure Tab URL" etc. I can't find any of this. The forms I have found ask for a whole load more information such as "Canvas Page", "Canvas URL", "Bookmark URL" and more, but I simply don't know what I'm supposed to put in here.

If anyone could advise me (in the most basic terms), or point me to a very simple tutorial then I would be most grateful.

EDIT: Think I have this sorted - thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to click `On Facebook` in order to display `Page Tabs`, which will display the `Tab URL`, `Secure Tab URL` and all of the `Canvas URL` details.

`Canvas Page` is the name you'd like for your application to show up on Facebook e.g. 
`http://apps.facebook.com/LaurasApp/`

`Canvas URL` is the `URL` to pull content for your application.

`Tab URL` is the `URL` to pull content for your Page.

`Secure Tab URL` is used if you are using `https`.

Comment: Hi, we're struggling to see the difference between the Canvas URL and the Tab URL. Lets' say we had an iframe at www.mysite.com/iframe/page.html, would that be the tab URL or the Canvas URL? And if it's one of those, what is the other one?

Comment: Apps on Facebook.com are loaded into a Canvas Page. A Canvas Page is quite literally a blank canvas within Facebook on which to run your app. You populate the Canvas Page by providing a Canvas URL that contains the HTML, JavaScript and CSS that make up your app. When a user requests the Canvas Page, we load the Canvas URL within an iframe on that page. This results in your app being displayed within the standard Facebook chrome.

Comment: okay: if my iframe is at "http://www.mysite.com/iframe.html", what goes in "canvas page", "canvas url" and "tab url", still struggling to see the differece!

Comment: `Canvas page` is the name of the `URL` that you want.  `Canvas URL` should just be `mysite.com/` and the `Tab URL` is where you specify the actual page you want to render.

Comment: Sorry - I am still having trouble! How do I get the content of my page (the URL I enter in "Tab URL") to show up as a tab on my Facebook page (on the left, alongside Wall, Discussions etc). And once that is done how do I make that the tab that visitors to my page see first?  Thanks :)

Comment: You need to add the application to the Facebook page.  When you goto the Application Page, there is an option on there to add it to your page.

Comment: Right - I think that's where I'm stuck. I can see from the Facebook documentation that I have to navigate to my app's Profile Page and then click "Add to my Page", but I can't figure out how to get to the app's profile page! What is the url for that? The only URLs I have are those of the canvas (http://apps.facebook.com/myApp/) and the actual content (http://mysite.com/appContent.html). Sorry and thank you.

Comment: In the developers page for you application, on the left hand side it says `View App Profile Page`.  Click this and it will take you where you need to go.  Then you can click `Add to my Page` on the left hand side.

Comment: You are welcome.  Glad you got there in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple tutorial that explains how to do it step-by-step. You should have no problems getting your custom page online by following this: http://webdeveloperpost.com/Articles/How-to-create-a-custom-facebook-page-without-restrictions.aspx